# Can libreoffice ppa be trusted if it has "no ultimately trusted keys"?

Tags: ppa, libreoffice, gnupg

Updating ppa's for libreoffice gets:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-5-0

...

Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

...
gpg: key 1378B444: public key "Launchpad PPA for LibreOffice Packaging" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

How then might libreoffice ppa not be trusted?

Comment: Yes, you can trust libreoffice in this case.

Comment: May I ask which Ubuntu version you're using? LibreOffice 5 is already included into the standard repositories of Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily).

Comment: I'm not using the latest version, BC, or I wouldn't be asking the question!

Answer (score 3):

I am quoting [the official Debian wiki page about SecureApt](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt#How_to_find_and_add_a_key):

> What does the "gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found" warning mean?
>
> The Warning: "no ultimately trusted keys found" means that gpg was not configured to ultimately trust a specific key. Trust settings are part of OpenPGPs Web-of-Trust which does not apply here. So there is no problem with this warning. In usual setups the users own key is ultimately trusted.

That means yes, you may trust the keys.

GPG is by default configured to only "ultimately trust" your own keys (if you ever created any).

Comment: Ah so then, it's like, April fools!, or Smile - you're on Candid Camera! - gotcha bozo! The warning this hardened security system just gave you can be completely ignored because it's meaningless! Ha ha. What a laugh. I can't wait for the one where cp tells you 'all files deleted' or firefox says trojan successfully downloaded. Oh what fun.

Comment: Ehm - no. Ultimate trust is something you should only have into yourself. It's pretty meaningless in this case, but not in general. Besides - as this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking on the grey tick on the left of it. Also please take two minutes to read our [tour] page where you will learn the most important things about AskUbuntu! Thanks.