# GPG keys error while installing sublime text editor and Oracle java

Tags: gnupg, keys

Reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04LTS and then upgraded to 16.01LTS still there is problem . How to resolve this issue.

```
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp_i5vkp5t/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp_i5vkp5t/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key EEA14886 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmp_i5vkp5t/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key EEA14886: public key "Launchpad VLC" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
```

Comment: [Edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/820443/edit) the question telling us what is actual problem installing them?

Comment: I followed the process of installing the above mentioned program it worked in other ubuntu system but this output comes in my system while adding ppa repository and Thank you for editing my question @Anwar

Answer (score 1):

Taking the question as it currently stands, I assume you're referring to this line as your problem

```
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
```

This is actually not a problem at all. It's just informing us about the key's authenticity level. Not every keys are ultimately trusted keys and it's not required at all!

It seems the keys are found and valid.

You should just proceed with the installation instruction.

Check this question to know about this message.

- [Can libreoffice ppa be trusted if it has "no ultimately trusted keys"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/693911/61218)

The answer there says, quoting from [Debian Wiki about SecureApt](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt#How_to_find_and_add_a_key)

> What does the "gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found" warning mean?
>
> The Warning: "no ultimately trusted keys found" means that gpg was not configured to ultimately trust a specific key. Trust settings are part of OpenPGPs Web-of-Trust which does not apply here. So there is no problem with this warning. In usual setups the users own key is ultimately trusted.

Comment: @ShailendraChaudhary Glad that I could understand your question. You can accept the answer if this _answered_ your question :)